# Force scanf to consume newline

Tags: c, newline, scanf

I have a program that reads data from `stdin`. This data is a sequence of bytes. If there is a byte describing a new line in it (in hex: 0x0A), `scanf` stops reading.

Can I mask this byte, so that `scanf` continues to read the whole sequence?

It is important that the memory, that is written by `scanf` contains the newline-byte.

Comment: where should your scanf stop?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your code, I can't make a precise recommendation. But if your goal is take the input "as-is", I'll recommend `read()` as an alternative to `scanf()`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237329/read-from-stdin-doesnt-ignore-newline/1237480#1237480) for someone who had the exact opposite issue.

Comment: There is no code. I only have the compiled binary and have to give an input to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%[^`]s", str);
```

You can use some thing like this. **`\n** will now be the terminating sequence of characters. 
You can replace **`** using any other character or even a group of them and input will end with that character followed by a **\n**.

Comment: Thats nearly what I'm looking for: to change the terminating sequence. The problem is: I only have the compiled binary and can only change the input...

Comment: in that case you can preprocess the input using regular expression s/\n//g which basically is substitute \n with \0... the expression used might depend on language (e.g. perl)/tool (e.g. sed) you use but this is usually the way it is

Comment: PS - i know it comes too late :P